# ¿Se puede relacionar 2 tablas de distintas base de datos por medio de una clave foránea?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 base de datos `Mysql` las cuales pueden ser `ejemplo1` y `ejemplo2`, una de las cuales `ejemplo1` no puedo tocar su estructura para nada por lo que me vi en la obligación de crear una propia `ejemplo2`, el asunto es que de la primera `ejemplo1` tiene datos de muchos usuarios los cuales necesito traer, pero no existe una tabla para guardar los datos de login al sistema (usuario y clave), esta tabla la estoy creando en `ejemplo2` en dicha tabla tengo pensado crear un campo `dni_user` el cual relacionaria con el campo `dni (Primary Key)` de `ejemplo1` y poder hacer las relaciones pertinentes con `laravel` y asi poder recuperar los datos del usuario que inicio sesión.

No estoy muy seguro que esto sea posible de relacionar 2 tablas de `Base de datos` distintas.

O en dado caso, solo conectar las 2 base de datos a mi sistema y hacer un `query` como por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    base1.*, base2.*
FROM 
    nombreBase1.nombreTabla base1
INNER JOIN 
    nombreBase2.nombreTabla base2 
ON base1.id=base2.id
```

En la cual incluyo mis 2 base de datos en la consulta

¿Es posible hacer esta relación median claves foraneas? ¿o tendria que hacerlo de la otra manera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puede ser del modo siguiente

```
SELECT (campo1, campo2, campo3)
FROM base1.tabla1 t1 JOIN base2.tabla2 t2 
ON t2.columna = t1.columna;
```

> Lo que necesitas es que al nombrar cada tabla, lleven como prefijo el
>   nombre de la base de datos de donde las planeas extraer; para que de
>   este modo se logren identificar

Obviamente necesitas verificar si tu usuario de base de datos tiene permisos sobre ambas bases, en caso afirmativo podrás hacerla operación sin mayor problema

Comment: Claro es lo que tengo pensado hacer, pero mi duda principal es si se pueden relacionar ambas tablas de distintas bases de datos por medio de una clave foranea, en caso de que no pues lo hago de este modo que me dices. Pero sabes si es posible relacionarlas por FK?

Comment: @EdwinAquino debe ser posible siempre que en el ON hagas match con los campos id de la tabla 1 con el a.id de la tabla 2 que esta actuando como llave foránea